# Will joining notification be send to my contact number if he doesn't have it?

Tags: telegram

Suppose I have synchronised my contact but the person in my contact do not have my contact number, **will he receive my joining notification in telegram app?**

Comment: No. Only those who have your contact will see that you joined even if you don't have their comtact. So someone who doesn't have your contact number will not get notified.

Answer (score 0):

No. He will only receive notifications of those people who are in his contact list.

Imagine a famous person getting 100s of notifications per day of people joining telegram he doesn't even know. LOL